# how access a gridview inside a repeater which is inside a repeater (Nested Repeater)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

How can I access `rep_DataSimilarToBacthid` ?

I need to bind the GridView and call GridView RowDataBound or InitializeRow

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_UnAssignComps" runat="server">

                 <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Repeater ID="rep_UnAssignComps" runat="server">

                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="rep_DataSimilarToBacthid" runat="server" Style="text-align: center;
                        width: 375px;" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Test" DataField="Test" />
                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

**I am using VB.Net with Framework Version 2.0. Thanks**

Comment: Lose the nesting, seriously :/

Comment: I need to bind the GridView and call GridView RowDataBound or InitializeRow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code behind add such function:

```
Protected Sub grid_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

End Sub
```

To your GridView control add OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound" so you get:

```
<asp:GridView ID="rep_DataSimilarToBacthid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound" ...
```